# Having trouble with javascript sort() order

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

This is my html code for that I put in an array to sort.  I am trying to get the numbers to sort in order from the lowest to the highest (in the ids). But all my code seems to do is resort from top to bottom while maintaining the current order.  Having looked around and trying a few different methods, I have not found a solution as of yet.  Any suggestions?

```
<a href="#" class="link-sort-list asc">A-Z</a> <a href="#" class="link-sort-list desc">Z-A</a>
<ul id="sortable">
<li id="220" class="p_box"></li>
<li id="221" class="p_box"></li>
<li id="217" class="p_box"></li>
<li id="215" class="p_box"></li>
<li id="219" class="p_box"></li>
<li id="216" class="p_box"></li>
<li id="218" class="p_box"></li>
<li id="214" class="p_box"></li>
<li id="208" class="p_box"></li>
<li id="206" class="p_box"></li>
</ul>
```

This is my javascript sort function.  The issue might be here but I am not sure.

```
var $list = $('#sortable');
var $myId = [];
var $myId = $(".p_box");
 //Sort Click Buttons
    $('.link-sort-list').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('asc')){
    $list.empty().append($myId.sort(function(a,b){return a < b}));
    } else {
    $list.empty().append($myId.sort());
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: See the documentation for `sort()`; your callback is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to sort by ID, and to sort the other way, reverse the condition

```
var $list = $('#sortable');

$('.link-sort-list').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('asc')) {
        $list.find('li').sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.id - b.id;
        }).appendTo($list);
    } else {
        $list.find('li').sort(function(a, b) {
            return b.id - a.id;
        }).appendTo($list);
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/QN3t6/)

Comment: Ah I get it now.  Before I was sorting just the list itself in the current order but not sorting by the id which with your interpretation makes it do that.  Thank you very much.  Really appreciate that assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/REh6J/2/):

```
$("#clickme").click(function(){
    var holder = [];

    $("#sortable").find("li").each(function(){
        holder.push($(this).attr("id"));
    });
    holder.sort();

    var length = holder.length, i = 0, k = 0;
    for (; i < length; i++){
        holder[i] = $("#" + holder[i]);
    }

    $("#sortable").children().remove();

    for (var k = length - 1; k > -1; k--){
        holder[k].insertAfter($("#sortable"));
    }
})
```

Comment: Interesting approach.  Would that also be able to work with associative arrays?

Comment: I believe so, but it would require a slightly different setup under the `.each()` block.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where `$list` and `$myId` come from but the function in sort should be:

```
return a - b;
```